# jqGrid JSON data includes Object Elements

Tags: json, jqgrid

My jqGrid gets its JSON data from a URL. It shows every columnt right however that JSON data's some elements are object. I want show that object element'S one property to be shown at my corresponding column. How can I do that?

**PS**: I will add data to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. ie. my object variable is `type` and I want to get element of `name` in. it. Just to write:

```
type.name
```

as name at colModel is enough.